# htaccess xampp - Redirect request to specific directory (many conditions)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp, localhost

Im working on a kind of mass virtual hosting app so i need the following things:

top of the htaccess document:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
```

Im running XAMPP localy so, I edited my etc/hosts in order to test requests.

1º detect hostname and rewrite to its folder inside the host:

so, following the above code I added this and it works correctly (as I tested):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.?.*\..*
RewriteRule .* %2/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

when i type **whatever.com** if it exist on hosts and there is a folder on /opt/lampp/htdocs/**whatever.com** browser go inside as spected

2º (the problem)

explanation: i need that request like **whatever.com**/admin go into other directory called /opt/lampp/htdocs/**admin** AND pass the hostname as a GET parameter, therefore **whatever.com/admin** internaly turns into **localhost/admin/?domain=whatever.com**

As you spect i get 404 and 500 without find a solution.

I think that is posible to add more rewrite cond.. in pseudo code entire file could be as follow

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.?.*\..*
RewriteRule .* %2/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule admin\/.*\.(!js|!css|php) /admin/?domain=%2 [NC,QSA,L] #redirect all request least the css and js files.
```

Many thanks.

*Sorry for my english. Educative system here sucks.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, i must test more this but i think is solved. Many thanks to Justin Iurman by the help.

Of course i added to the rwrule RewriteRule ^admin/**(.*)?**$ BACKEND-PHP/**$1**?domain=%1 [L,QSA,NC] in order to rewrite all the files.

so htaccess looks as following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)?$ BACKEND-PHP/$1?domain=%1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

How if the request looks like http://whatever.com/admin/ANYSCRIPT_OR_VOID it goes to **localhost/BACKEND-PHP/ANYSCRIPT OR VOID?domain=whatever.com**

css and js files works as spected too.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin/?domain=%1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I changed this "RewriteBase /" for this "RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$"

it works but, its not answereda at 100%, sorry if i dont expained very well. 

I also need that css and js files dont get rewrited.

Comment: Even dont work if i type this in the broswer "http://hostname.com/admin/post_list.php", it outputs 404 when i write  an address to another location, not the admin/

Comment: I just solved the problem to the request with other files:

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*\.php)?$ BACKEND-PHP/$1?domain=%1 [L,QSA,NC]

But i also need that css and js dont get 404. 

(css and js files had a relaive path, this is not mandatory)